# Can a class declared in Groovy script be accessed in javassist?

Tags: java, groovy, jvm, javassist

I have a Groovy script which declares a certain class. Can I access this class in the same script through javassist? I need to create a CtClass object for it.

Here is an example of the script, test.groovy:

```
import javassist.*;

public class TestClass {
    public String testMethod(String x) {
        return x + ".";
    }
}

// I can use TestClass now for ordinary operations
TestClass obj = new TestClass();
println(obj.testMethod("a"));

ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault(); // ?
CtClass cc = pool.getCtClass("TestClass"); // this doesn't work
```

The last string causes an error:

```
Caught: javassist.NotFoundException: TestClass
javassist.NotFoundException: TestClass
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
    at javassist.ClassPool.getCtClass(ClassPool.java:515)
    at javassist.ClassPool$getCtClass$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at test.run(test.groovy:14)
```

It's of course possible to move this class outside of the script and compile it to a .class file and then it's easy to load it. I think it's also possible in the script to, say, dynamically compile this class again to a byte array or to a .class file and then to load it in javassist. But is it possible to do this without additional (re)compilation of this class and to use the class which I already can access in ordinary operations?

Answer (score 1):

You can register custom code sources to a Javassist `ClassPool`. By default, Javassist reads class files from the class path if you call `ClassPool.getDefault()`. You would need to get hold of the class files from Groovy.

One way to do this would be to read the class files from a Java agent that allows to read a class file using a `ClassFileTransformer`. Another way would be to hook into the Groovy class loader that loads the script where all classes are passed through `findClass`.